# Interfacing an R305 fingerprint sensor with TM4C123 (Tiva Launchpad)

Tags: fingerprint, texas-instruments

I'm currently working on my semester project which includes interfacing the **R305 Fingerprint Sensor** to **TM4C123** microcontroller (by Texas Instruments).
The fingerprint sensor communicates to the microcontroller through UART interface and so it has 4 pins to connect to the microcontroller: Vcc, GND, Tx, Rx, as given in the datasheet at the following address.

http://www.rhydolabz.com/documents/finger-print-module.pdf

From the datasheet, I could understand that in order to assure the perfect connection between the microcontroller and the fingerprint sensor, the first thing is the **HandShake**, in which a certain **Command Packet** is sent to the sensor and the sensor returns the corresponding **Acknowledgement Packet**. But in my case, I'm sending the command packet to the fingerprint sensor and the sensor is sending nothing back.
The sensor works fine with arduino when using the Adafruit Library, but I have to work with the TM4C123 MCU for my project.
I'm using Keil uvision 4 as an IDE for my MCU.

Answer (score 0):

The pdf clearly states that **Commands shall only be sent from upper computer to the Module, and the Module 
acknowledges the commands**.

By upper computer it means pc .

Comment: But Adafruit has developed a library to interface the sensor with arduino. Link is below.

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library?files=1

So if we can interface the sensor with arduino, we should be able to  do the same with other MCUs that support UART.

Answer (score 0):

It's a micro controller, just like an Arduino. But you just don't get the ton's of libraries and tutorials that are available for arduino.

These MCU work internally are very different - different registers, different process for using them, different gotchas to look out for, etc. If you're looking at tackling a new MCU family, be prepared to effectively learn a new "language".

Incidentally, the Launchpads from Texas Instruments have a processing-based language similar to the Arduino - called [Energia](http://energia.nu) - which should work on your TM4C123.

The [Energia IDE](http://energia.nu) is a port of the Arduino IDE and significantly simplifies configuration and programming Tiva C launchpads.

Comment: Few years back I worked with it but due to unavailability of libraries and support i changed to arduino.You might be even wanna develop some headerfiles by yourself

Comment: I believe Energia might help you.

Comment: Is it the IDE that runs arduino-like codes on other MCUs! I tried it using the same library that Adafruit created for Arduino after configuring it for desired pins of my TM4C123 MCU. But it gave me error on "SoftwareSerial.h" library that is present in arduino but not in Energia. Googling a little bit, it come out that "SoftwareSerial.h" is the library used to serially interface devices through UART.
I couldn't find any similar library for energia. Can you suggest any ?

Comment: But energia do support `SoftwareSerial​` .Have you added library before using it?

Comment: WARNING: Spurious .github folder in 'Adafruit Fingerprint Sensor Library' library
C:\Users\Muhammad Abdullah\Documents\Energia\libraries\Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library-master\examples\enroll\enroll.ino:18:28: fatal error: SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory

 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

                            ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board LaunchPad (Tiva C) w/ tm4c123 (80MHz).
 **This was The Exact Error!**

Comment: I discussed the matter with my lab instructor and theory teacher. According to them, the fingerprint sensor might not be perfectly compatible to the TM4C123 MCU because the minimum supply current the sensor requires is 90mA and the max output current that the GPIOs of the MCU can provide is 25 mA.
So, they suggested me to use an output buffer to amplify the output current !